# I tried to pass Json data to view using angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

Just im trying to pass my data using `Angular JS` but im getting blank page 
i choose this example http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_sql

Then i tried from my local database like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>@{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>@{{ x.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost/sample/public/foo")
                .then(function (response) {
                    $scope.names = response.data.hotels;
                });
        });
</script>
```

My http://localhost/sample/public/foo out put is like below so what im doing wrong

```
"{"hotels":[{"id":1,"name":"Sanmira Renaissance"},{"id":2,"name":"Galadari Hotel"},{"id":3,"name":"Grand Oriental Hotel"},{"id":4,"name":"Fullmoon Garden Hotel"},{"id":5,"name":"Ramada Hotel \u2013 Colombo"},{"id":6,"name":"Taj Samudra"},{"id":7,"name":"Cinnamon Grand"},{"id":8,"name":"Cinnamon Lakeside"}]}"
```

Comment: Is your response a string instead of a JSON? What happens when you run $scopes.names = JSON.parse(response.data.hotels); ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your JSON which is not formated correctly, and change your controller like this,

```
app.controller("listController", ["$scope","$http",
    function($scope, $http) {
             $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
                $scope.hotels = response.data.hotels;

        });

}]);
```

Working [`application`](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Gnubm6rd14COPq9jER2?p=preview)

Comment: don't we need to define $http and still im getting blank page why ? im doing this in my laravel blade template so i changed only this  `@{{item.name}}`

Comment: in your json data first " " doesn't have but my JSON data it has how to ignore that

Comment: Then it is not a proper json, you need to handle from the server side

Comment: No bro @sajeetharan im working on laravel project so this is how im generate data  `$hotels = App\HvAccountHotel::all();
    $output = json_encode(array('hotels' => $hotels));
        dd($output);`

Comment: if you can give team viewer i can check

Comment: thanks can you tell me the suitable time then i can come online i need ur help